# Diebold-Mariano Test in R - how to rationalize p-value?

Tags: r, forecasting, diebold-mariano-test

Consider 3 models (model1, model2, model3) with the following set of prediction errors:

```
residuals_model1=c(-0.0422,-0.0198,-0.0167,-0.0350,-0.0084,-0.0387,0.0232,0.0239,-0.0104,-0.0174,0.0292,-0.0169,0.0456,-0.0068,0.0372,0.0557,0.0003,-0.0090)
residuals_model2=c(0.0109,-0.0129,-0.0058,0.0192,0.0055,0.0288,-0.0285,-0.0254,0.0013,0.0089,-0.0317,0.0319,-0.0262,0.0140,-0.0156,-0.0404,0.0190,0.0308)
residuals_model3=c(0.0189,0.0035,0.0025,0.0222,0.0004,0.0340,-0.0232,-0.0238,0.0145,0.0238,-0.0215,0.0243,-0.0379,0.0092,-0.0322,-0.0541,-0.0042,0.0111)
```

Computing root mean squared forecast errors (RMSFE):

```
rmsfe_model1=sqrt(mean(residuals_model1^2))
rmsfe_model2=sqrt(mean(residuals_model2^2))
rmsfe_model3=sqrt(mean(residuals_model3^2))
```

Next, create a matrix with the relative RMSFE of models 2 & 3 versus model 1 and the relevant p-values from the Diebold-Mariano test using the forecast package:

```
library(forecast)
forecast_results=matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2)
rownames(forecast_results)=c('model2 / model1','model3 / model1')
colnames(forecast_results)=c('relative RMSFE','p-value (DM-Test)')
forecast_results[1,1]=round(rmsfe_model2/rmsfe_model1,2)
forecast_results[2,1]=round(rmsfe_model3/rmsfe_model1,2)
forecast_results[1,2]=round(dm.test(residuals_model1,residuals_model2,alternative='two.sided',h=1,power=2)$p.value,2)
forecast_results[2,2]=round(dm.test(residuals_model1,residuals_model3,alternative='two.sided',h=1,power=2)$p.value,2)
```

Print results:

```
print(forecast_results)

                relative RMSFE p-value (DM-Test)
model2 / model1           0.79              0.10
model3 / model1           0.85              0.04
```

It can be seen that model 2 performs better in terms of relative RMSFE compared to model 3. However, the p-value from the DM-test shows a higher level of statistical significance for model 3 compared to model 2.

Suppose you had to present this table of results and somebody would claim that a higher relative RMSFE for model 3 is inconsistent with a lower p-value for model 3. How would you explain this result?

Comment: The residuals plots show a break in the last period. If you exclude that, the p-values are almost the same, as model2 and model3 are not different according to `dm.test`. Why your reference model is negative correlated (almost perfect in one case) with the other models?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with the break in the last period! And good point regarding the negative correlation, I have to investigate this as it looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Regarding the correlation, most probably the sign of the residual vector from model 1 or the sign of the residual vectors from models 2 & 3 should be reversed (note that this would not change the above results). Model 1 refers to an autoregressive model and models 2 & 3 refer to an autoregressive distributed lag model. Side note: ARDL models are estimated via Bayesian Model Averaging so the AR model is not a fully nested version of the former.